# python, h2o.import_file() return empty line

Tags: python, h2o

i have some problem with read files in h2o.

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.deeplearning import H2ODeepLearningEstimator
h2o.init()
train = h2o.import_file("("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv"")
splits = train.split_frame(ratios=[0.75], seed=1234)
dl = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(distribution="quantile",quantile_alpha=0.8)
dl.train(x=range(0,2), y="petal_len", training_frame=splits[0])
print(dl.predict(splits[1]))
```

UPDATE_1, The fourth line has this form(sorry, i copied wrong from IDE):

```
train = h2o.import_file("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")
```

I got H2OTypeError: Argument `x` should be a None | integer | string | list(string | integer) | set(integer | string), got range range(0, 2).

This is due to the fact that "train" is empty.

```
In [23]: train

Out[23]:
```

I thought that there is a problem with reading from and linking and manually downloading file.

```
train = h2o.import_file("iris_wheader.csv")
```

But i got same result.

```
In [26]: train

Out[26]:
```

I connected pandas and open this .csv in pandas. It opened, I got a pandas-dataframe, I used

```
 train = h2o.H2OFrame(train)
```

and got an empty train.

```
In [29]: train

Out[29]:
```

How to solve this problem?

UPDATE_2 When I went to 127.0.0.1:54321/flow/index.html, and it shows me that the dataframe has been loaded into the cluster. But in Python, I get empty train. I use Spyder IDE with IPython console, can it somehow influence the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with this line:

```
train = h2o.import_file("("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv"")
```

You have extra " and (, it should be:

```
train = h2o.import_file("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")
```

Then you'll see that `train` and also `print(train)` give output:

```
In [6]: train
Out[6]:   sepal_len    sepal_wid    petal_len    petal_wid  class
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
        5.1          3.5          1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.9          3            1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.7          3.2          1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.6          3.1          1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
        5            3.6          1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        5.4          3.9          1.7          0.4  Iris-setosa
        4.6          3.4          1.4          0.3  Iris-setosa
        5            3.4          1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.4          2.9          1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.9          3.1          1.5          0.1  Iris-setosa

[150 rows x 5 columns]


In [7]: train.nrow
Out[7]: 150

In [8]: print(train)
  sepal_len    sepal_wid    petal_len    petal_wid  class
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
        5.1          3.5          1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.9          3            1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.7          3.2          1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.6          3.1          1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
        5            3.6          1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        5.4          3.9          1.7          0.4  Iris-setosa
        4.6          3.4          1.4          0.3  Iris-setosa
        5            3.4          1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.4          2.9          1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
        4.9          3.1          1.5          0.1  Iris-setosa

[150 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I did not correctly copy the code, in the first example, it does not look like that. It looks like you specified. But i have empty train. But I went to http://127.0.0.1:54321/flow/index.html, and it shows me that the dataframe has been loaded into the cluster. But in Python, I get empty train. I use Spyder with IPython console, can it somehow influence the result?

Comment: What happens when you do: `train.nrow`?  It might be an issue with the console not printing rather than the fact that the dataset is not there.  You can confirm by checking the number of rows.

Comment: In [3]:train
Out[3]:   
In [4]:train.nrow
Out[4]: 150; Yes, This issue with the console. Could the encoding be the cause? I use the Russian language Spyder, with the encoding utf-8.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your specific IDE. It works fine in a regular IPython shell. If you see the data frame when you use `print(train)` or `head(train)` then I'd recommend using that instead.

Comment: Thank you, its problem with my IDE. I started the ipython without the IDE. Variables are displayed. But the error remains, I removed the string `x=range(0,2)`, and the program worked, both in IDE and in the simple ipython console. But since I took an example in DeepLearningBooklet from [link](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepLearningBooklet.pdf). I want to ask, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code works for me on Python 2.7. Are you using Python 3.6 perhaps?  See if it works if you set `x=[0,1]` instead of `x=range(0,2)`.